# Property fields retrieving data from another model

Tags: python, django, authentication, properties, model

I do not know if there is such a thing as possible, I have little experience in it, so I ask. Is such a solution possible? I need a `User` and a `Profile` with `email` and `password` - `AbstractBaseUser`, the `Profile` will be connected to the User using the OneToOne relationship. As below:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profil(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', max_length=254, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

In the model, the User needs to fill in the username field that is required. How can I use property to relate to a Profile model and download data for a User model?

Comment: This question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need a property at all? What would it do? (And, assuming you do need it, where are you having problems defining it?)

Comment: And after all that, it's not clear why you need a separate Profile model at all, considering you have a custom User class anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a Profile model in a different schema, a User model in a public schema. I need these models to "see" each other.
I need the Profile model in a different schema so that the user can log in to the schema where he is registered.

Comment: But I still don't understand. You already have a OneToOneField, why can't you use that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman When registering, I give my email and password - data for the AbstractBaseUser model, i.e. Profile - it is in a different schema, where there will also be a possibility of resetting the password, etc. The User model is needed for connection to the public schema. The question is, can I use the OneToOne relation to fill in the required fields in the User model?